# Why do my database customizations not get applied when using Spring Data JPA with Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm trying to use Spring Data JPA in a Spring Boot project in this  [tutorial](http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/10/27/using-mysql-in-spring-boot-via-spring-data-jpa-and-hibernate). These are my `pom.xml` dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and `application.properties`

```
# DataSource settings: set here configurations for the database connection
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost/dao
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.password = 

# Specify the DBMS
spring.jpa.database = MYSQL

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate settings are prefixed with spring.jpa.hibernate.*
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
```

and I get this error:

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot         determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an    embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath.
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:137)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.dataSource(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:117)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiat   e(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
... 40 more
```

Is there a problem in datasource configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is thrown in `DataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName()` method. Find below the source code of the same from spring distribution:

```
if (!StringUtils.hasText(driverClassName)) {
    throw new BeanCreationException(
        "Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type "
            + this.embeddedDatabaseConnection
            + ". If you want an embedded "
            + "database please put a supported one on the classpath.");
}
```

Spring throws this error when `spring.datasource.driverClassName` property is empty. So to fix this error, make sure that the `application.properties` is in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into that same error and my problem was that the application.properties was not packaged in the 
jar and I wasn't providing it on startup.

If you are starting up using java -jar you-jar-name.jar make sure that the application.properties is available.  Per the docs:

SpringApplication will load properties from application.properties files in the following locations and add them to the Spring Environment:

A /config subdir of the current directory.
The current directory
A classpath /config package
The classpath root

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files